# How to compile the program which uses shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Client.h

```
#ifndef TEST_CLIENT_H_
#define TEST_CLIENT_H_

#include <memory>

class SimpleClient {
public:
  virtual int GetProgress() const = 0;
  virtual char* CutPrefix(char* data) = 0;
  virtual ~SimpleClient() {}
};

std::shared_ptr<SimpleClient> CreateSimpleClient();

#endif  // TEST_CLIENT_H_
```

Client.cpp

```
#include "client.h"

namespace {

class SimpleClientImpl : public SimpleClient {
private:
  int progress_counter_;

public:
  SimpleClientImpl() : progress_counter_(0) {}

  int GetProgress() const;
  char* CutPrefix(char* data);
};

int SimpleClientImpl::GetProgress() const {
  return progress_counter_;
}

char* SimpleClientImpl::CutPrefix(char* data) {
  progress_counter_++;
  return data + *reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(data) + sizeof(size_t);
}

}  // namespace

std::shared_ptr<SimpleClient> CreateSimpleClient() {
  return std::shared_ptr<SimpleClient>(new SimpleClientImpl);
}
```

I tried to compile: g++ -c client.cpp and got below error

In file included from client.cpp:2:
client.h:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â€˜<â€™ token
client.cpp:27: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â€˜<â€™ token

I understood from the various posts that I should link with goose library, but don't know how to use it.

this is the compiler version I am using:

g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 20101112 (Red Hat 4.4.5-2) (GCC)

Could anybody help me please.

Comment: You need to pass the `-std=c++11` flag (or later) to gcc, assuming the libstdc++ version bundled with gcc 4.4.5 even includes `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

For a compiler that old you should probably add -std=c++0x instead of -std=c++11 to the compiler flags.